# Array creates a NULL record at the end PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am a bit new to arrays in php, I have a function that connects to my DB and returns the result for me in a array, once I have the array to use it in smarty i have to disassemble it basically and create a new array.

I have been using a for loop to achieve this. But everytime the for loop runs, i end up with a NULL record as my last value.

If there are 13 records returned, it creates 14 for some reason.

Any advice is welcome :).

```
$permissionsarray=db_select("select group_name from `user_groups` order by group_name");
for($i = 0; $permissions[$i] = $permissionsarray[$i]['group_name']; $i++) ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for-loop tests whether `$permissions[$i]` evaluates to something "truthy" - if it doesn't (probably NULL in your case) the deed is already done, i.e. $permissions[$i] has already been assigned.

The immediate solution would be something like

```
$permissionsarray=db_select("select group_name from `user_groups` order by group_name");
for($i = 0;  $p = $permissionsarray[$i]['group_name']; $i++) {
    $permissions[$i] = $p;
}
```

(and that would probably still raise an undefined index warning).

But there's no need to "handle" the indexing yourself. With a [foreach](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)-loop you can iterate the array regardless of the actual keys used. And with [] you can append items to an array without keeping track of the "next key" yourself.

```
$permissions = array();
foreach( db_select("select group_name from `user_groups` order by group_name") as $p ) {
    $permissions[] = $p['group_name'];
}
```

but there's an even simpler way

```
$permissionsarray=db_select("select group_name from `user_groups` order by group_name");
$permissions = array_column($permissionsarray, 'group_name');
```

see http://docs.php.net/array_column
(if you're using php < php5.5 there's a link to a fill-in for that function that works with older versions of php)

Comment: The immediate solution would be `foreach()`.  But Yay! for `array_column()`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver : yes, but I wanted the "immediate solution" to be as close to the original code as possible, since my description at the beginning isn't that clear ;-) - but I will add a foreach-snippet as well...

Comment: Thank you @VolkerK prefered the last solution. Most simple